# What is it mean Difficuly & prob when using vanitygen?

Tags: wallet, address, vanity-address, vanitygen

I am running this command

```
$ vanitygen64.exe 1abcdefg
Difficulty: 778316249440
[125.17 Kkey/s][total 39015067414][Prob 4.9%][50% in 46.3d]
```

1. What is it mean `Difficulty`? I understand that higher takes more time, but what is the scale, why it is different from total? Why alphabet is more difficult than only digits `vanitygen`1234567`?
2. What is it mean `50%` in 46 days, why it not tell me 100%. After 46 days, how much percent will be that it will complete in the next 46 days? If it is same reasons  as in [Half-Life in nuclear physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) I understand it.
3. The big question. What it is **`Prob 4.9%`**? `Prob` of what?

Comment: General warning: use of vanity addresses is bad. Bad for yourself and bad for others you transact with. Address re-use is bad for privacy and safety.

Comment: I know. But it is for a gift. Giving someone BTC on his name, then he can use it once...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Difficulty tells you how likely it is that vanitygen will be able to find the address pattern you're looking for on the next guess. A value of 2n is twice as difficult (half as likely) than a value of n.
2. Because the process is completely random, it's impossible to give you a '100%' ETA. We can only estimate that, on average, you will find your key before some time period *half* the time (hence why 50% is used). Note that it re-adjusts the value to 75% once it hits that 50% mark (and re-adjusts again after hitting 75%, until the key is eventually found).
3. That is the likelihood that you would have found your key by *now*, from the time when you started generating your key.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why finding alphabet is more difficult that finding only digits address: `1abcdef` takes more time than `1123456`